# Dimension of a quasivariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $f_1, ...f_n$ be $n$ homogenuous polynomials, on variable $z_0, z_1, ..., z_n$. Let $V=V(f_1, ..., f_n)$ be the projective variety in $P^n$. Let $V_1=V\bigcap \{ z_0=1\}$ and $V_2=V\bigcap \{ z_0=0\}$. Then $V=V_1\bigcup V_2$. I want to get some criterion to see if $V_1$ is of  dimension $>0$. For example, if $V_1$ has positive dimension, does it hold that $V_1\bigcap \{ z_i=z_j \}\neq \emptyset$ for all pairs of $i\ge1,j\ge1$?

Comment: No. Take $n=2$ and consider the variety $V(x_0+x_1+x_2)\subset\Bbb P^2$. There are plenty of methods for computing $\dim V_1$ - why do you want to use this one in particular?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see. I know little on these matter. Can you suggest some readings on criterion of positive dimension of a quasi-projective variety, or name some of those methods? Thanks in advance.